# Integerate Google Apps for Education with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-apps

I have a GAFE account, but I need to login using my website's login page as a social network.
How do I integrate Google Apps For Education login in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Comment: Look into OAuth and OpenID - Google has an OpenID provider, so you can probably use the GAFE account to get an OpenID token and log in with that.

Answer (score 0):

Source code here
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth

Samples here
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/latest/download

Step by step Instruction here
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: I am asking how to integrate google app for eduction. not gamil or fb